# admin.ref.on() is not working while once() works perfectly

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found this strange problem where documented feature seems not to be working.

I have this working code:

```
exports.getEvents = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

cors(req, res, () => {
    admin.database().ref('events').orderByValue().once('value', function(snapshot) {

        res.status(200).send(snapshot.val());

    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error while reading data', error);
        res.status(403).send('Error: ' + error);
    });
```

When I change from `once()` to `on()` I get errors.

What I want to achieve is to have server send new JSON payload when there are changes to `events`since I have app that reads `events.json` directly and I can use only link to provide data (so all SDK functions are out). Am I doing something wrong?

Error log:

```
TypeError: admin.database(...).ref(...).orderByValue(...).on(...).catch is not a function
at cors (/user_code/index.js:24:11)
at cors (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
at /user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
at originCallback (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
at /user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
at optionsCallback (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
at corsMiddleware (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
at exports.getEvents.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:19:2)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:47)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:635:7
```

Comment: What errors? Can you share security rules and sample data?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with security since `once()` method works perfectly. I updated my question with error log from dashboard - maybe that will help.

Answer (score 4):

You've tried to add a `.catch` to the end of your statement. `.on` doesn't support this function.

See some sample code below which should fix your issue.

```
admin.database().ref('/somePath')
  .orderByValue()
  .on('child_added', (snapshot, prevChildKey) => {
     console.log(snapshot.val()); // JSON 
  }, err => {
     // Error is thrown here - Not in a .catch
  });
```

Comment: It's working now, but seems like it's not updating when there is a change in database - maybe Firebase doesn't support that, but why would they implement `on()` then?

Comment: It will only fire when a new child is added to `/somePath`. It won't fire for an update, only a new write.

Comment: Tried that - not working :/ Only after refresh new data shows up.